# Fetching columns, 4 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I’ve ran in to some problems with the following SQL assignment. I’m to retrieve the ID, firstname and lastname of any member who is registered in section that contains the word ‘xyz’.

So far I’ve managed the following:

```
SELECT m.id, p.firstname, p.lastname FROM member m
INNER JOIN person p ON m.id = p.id
WHERE m.id IN (SELECT id FROM membersection);
```

How do I go forward from here? I have no idea how to retrieve the sectionid from the membersection table then fetch the section name from the section id using that ID so I can check if the section name contains the previously stated word.

**member:**

id 
member_number 
registration_date

**membersection:**

memberid
sectionid

**person:**

id
firstname
lastname

**section:**

id
name

Comment: It would help to see some example data; for instance, is member.id the same as membersection.memberid, or is member.member_number the same as membersection.memberid?  How does person.id relate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep joining. And in the end use `LIKE` to check if `section.name` contains `'xyz'`.

```
SELECT m.id,
       p.firstname,
       p.lastname
       FROM member m
            INNER JOIN person p
                       ON p.id = m.id
            INNER JOIN membersection ms
                       ON ms.memberid = m.id
            INNER JOIN section s
                       ON s.id = ms.sectionid
       WHERE s.name LIKE '%xyz%';
```

Answer (score 2):

There is some ambiguity in your question with regards to how your data are structured; what are the primary and foreign keys?

But, making some assumptions, you're almost there, you can chain multiple join statements together:

```
select
  m.id,
  p.firstname,
  p.lastname
from
  member m
  inner join person p on
    m.id = p.id
  inner join membersection ms on
    m.id = ms.memberid
  inner join section s on
    ms.sectionid = s.id
where
  s.name like '%xyz%'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not super obvious what's going on with your Data Relationships, but this would be the basic route you might want to take (`LEFT JOIN` as I do not know the relationship):

```
SELECT m.id, p.firstname, p.lastname, ms.sectionid
FROM member m
INNER JOIN person p ON m.id = p.id 
LEFT JOIN section s ON m.id = s.id
LEFT JOIN membersection ms ON m.id = ms.memberid
WHERE s.name = 'xyz'
```